# What is the meaning of "As death embraces"

Tags: grammar, as

What do you understand in this phrase?, what is the function of as?
EDIT: **As death embraces** is the title of a song.

Here is the lyrics:

> Forgive my daily sins
>   Seal them under my skin
>   For once I watched you fly
>   Leaving your wings behind
>   The path of fate has gone astray
>   The brightest skies have turned to grey

Comment: This is a sentence fragment - it will be easier to explain the meaning if you provide the whole sentence and preferably some of the surrounding material.

Comment: sorry, is the title of a song i will provide the lyrics.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's opinion-based Lit Crit, not "learning English" as such.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: we can give the literal meaning of the phrase.

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo: The literal meanings of the three words can all be looked up in a dictionary, which OP can do for himself. Anything anyone here might add is just contextualised opinion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As death embraces...

That phrase can be taken in one of two ways.

**As** can be understood temporally:

> She looked out her car window **as** she drove past the accident.

**as** introduces something that is happening concurrently with something else.

Or **as** can be understood as making a comparison:

> I want you to copy his tennis swing. Hold the tennis racket back **as** he does.

There, it means "in the same manner".

So, your phrase could imply that something is transpiring at the same time as death is embracing something or someone, or it could imply that something is happening that is similar to the way that death embraces something or someone.

"embrace" means to "hold with the arms, to hug", so with respect to what it means for "death" to "embrace" something, all we can say is that death is holding something or someone (as if death were able to embrace). It is a figure of speech. As FumbleFingers remarked in his comment, we cannot get into what that means because interpretation of poems and lyrics is considered off-topic here on this site.

Comment: thanks,  i understand you and i didn't know that phrase was in a figurative sense (rather incomplete).